A script for extracting and importing strings from a DLL file, with Resource Hacker software
I am trying to translate software into my language.
The language files are inside DLL files.
I previously translated the software, but it got an update, and now I have to start again.
A friend built me ​​a script for comparison, I will attach it at the end of the post, but I saw that it is possible to extract using the command line, and if so it is much better to create an automatic extraction and comparison script!
Problems:

When I try to run a script I just don't succeed... I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to build a script that would output all the menus, popups, and strings to files.
Then I will combine it with what I have.
I would be happy if there was a way to also send for machine translation [prefers Bing, more accurate than Google].
Thank you very much!
PS I'm a weak programmer... I'd appreciate it if you could explain well!

Hope this is well written... English is not my language at all...
Here is the comparison script:
It is based on reading the source file in the old version, and comparing it to the source file in the new version.
If the line matches - he takes the line from the translated file, and pastes into a new file, which is actually a translated file of the new version.
Hope I explained myself.
The script works with TXT files, and extracting them without an automatic script is a huge job...
That's why I need a script, which will extract the TXT files quickly...
import csv

def chek(file_path):
    dict_ver = {}
    with open(file_path, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as input:
        content = input.readlines()
        for line in content:
            words = line.split('"')
            try:
                dict_ver[words[0].strip('"')] = words[1].strip('"')
            except IndexError:
                print("ssss")
        return dict_ver

old_file = "15.txt"
new_file = "16.txt"
old_file_en = "en_15.txt"
with open("16.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
    content = input_file.read()

new_dict = chek(new_file)
old_dict = chek(old_file)
old_dict_en = chek(old_file_en)
dict_foo = []
for id in new_dict:
    if old_dict_en.get(id) == new_dict[id]:
        content = content.replace(new_dict[id], old_dict[id])
    else:
        print(id)
        #dict_foo[id] = new_dict[id]
        dict_foo.append([id, new_dict[id], old_dict_en.get(id), old_dict.get(id)])
with open("16 new.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as foo:
    foo.write(content)
with open("log.csv", "w", encoding="windows-1255", newline="") as log_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(log_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["id", "16", "15 en", "15 heb"])
    for i in dict_foo:
        csv_writer.writerow(i)

        
"""
i = 0
t = 0
for key in new_dict:
    if key not in old_dict:
        print(key)
        i += 1
    else:
        t += 1
print(i)
print(t)
"""    


I tried the command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Hacker>ResourceHacker.exe -open "my.dll" -save "my.rc" -action extract -mask "STRING TABLES" 
But I get a lot of BIN files, and one RC file that contains them all, and I don't know how to put it back into the DLL.
I thought I would get each menu and window as a separate RC file.
